# Ignoring MACRO argument

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a macro that I use at end of functions:

```
#define FN_EXIT(x) \
cout << "Message"; \
return x;
```

If I use it as `FN_EXIT(1)`, it works okay. Can I use it as `FN_EXIT()` for `void` returning functions? If not, is there of a passing an argument that would work with `return` statement of a `void` function?

Comment: Avoid macros as much as you can. Especially buggy macros like yours (try doing something like `if (condition) FN_EXIT(y);` and see what happens).

Comment: Compiling with `-E` (gcc or clang) allows you to see what the compiler does with your macro. So you can try with no argument, and see that it will work for a `void` function. And you can try with an `if` statement and see why you shouldn't be doing this.